# what does this regular expression match?

Tags: java, regex

I came across this expression and am trying to figure out what regular expression would match to?

```
new Text(Arrays.toString(parts).replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")
```

I used [Xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/) to generate some string but it is probably not showing the right strings because it keeps generating only 2 strings ^[ and ]$

Comment: What is your guess? Which part of this regex is unclear? Do you know `^` means in regex? What about `$` or `|`? Do you know the role of ``\\``?

Comment: Did you notice `[` and `]` are *escaped*, that is, they are to be matched literally?

Comment: Does it mean starts with [ (or) ends with ] ?

Comment: Yep, your regex matches the symbol `[` which was at the start **OR** `]` at the end.

Comment: Is it "[ at the start and ] at the end" or either one of those?

Comment: your regex matches `[` in `[foo` or `]` in `foo]` or both `[`,`]` in `[foobar]`

Comment: both???? what do you mean?

Comment: This single regex does not match *both*. Either it matches the left half, OR (the `|`) it matches the right half. `foo|bar` matches `foo` OR `bar`, never `foobar`, as both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your regex does is to match a starting `[` and an ending `]`

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fF5aZ8/1)**

[image]

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HVQqnDynik2H641_)

Explanation from regex101:

```
1st Alternative: ^\[
    ^ assert position at start of a line
    \[ matches the character [ literally
2nd Alternative: \]$
    \] matches the character ] literally
    $ assert position at end of a line
```

So, this code:

```
"[sdfsad sdfsd]asdfas]".replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")
```

Will remove the starting and ending `[` `]`, and the resulting string would be:

```
sdfsad sdfsd]asdfas
```

Comment: @user2023507 glad to help. Thank for the tick. Also check debuggex.com for to have a graphic view

Comment: `|` is OR, not AND. Both halves get matched, but by Java's `replaceAll`, not due to the Regex itself.

Comment: @Jongware I know that `|` means regex OR, but I wasn't explaining the regex literally. If you see in the screenshot the 4th example it matches both `[` and `]`. That's why I said "and". But yes, you are right `|` means OR in regex engines.